# Write a shell script that find-greps and outputs filename and content in 1 line

Tags: bash, shell, find, grep

To see all the php files that contain "abc" I can use this simple script:

```
find . -name "*php" -exec grep -l abc {} \;
```

I can omit the -l and i get extracted some part of the content instead of the filenames as results:

```
find . -name "*php" -exec grep abc {} \;
```

What I would like now is a version that does both at the same time, but on the same line.

Expected output:

```
path1/filename1: lorem abc ipsum
path2/filename2: ipsum abc lorem
path3/filename3: non abc quod
```

More or less like `grep abc *` does.

**Edit:** I want to use this as a simple shell script. It would be great if the output is on one line, so further grepping would be possible. But it is not necessary that the script is only one line, i am putting it in a bash script file anyways.

**Edit 2:** Later I found "ack", which is a great tool and I use this now in most cases instead of grep. It does all this and more. http://betterthangrep.com/ You would write `ack --php --nogroup abc` to get the desired result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-H` switch ([`man grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)):

```
find . -name "*php" -exec grep -H abc {} \;
```

Alternative using [`xargs`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) (now the `-H` switch is not needed, at least for the version of `grep` I have here):

```
find . -name "*php" -print | xargs grep abc
```

---

**Edit:** As a consequence of `grep`'s behavior as noted by [orsogufo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15622/orsogufo), the second command above should use `-H` if [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) could conceivably return only a single filename (i.e. if there is only a single PHP file). If orsogufo's comment w.r.t. `-print0` is also incorporated, the command becomes:

```
find . -name "*php" -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H abc
```

**Edit 2:** A (more<sup>1</sup>) [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compliant version as proposed by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), which through the use of `/dev/null` avoids the `-H` switch:

```
find . -name "*php" -print0 | xargs -0 grep abc /dev/null
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: A quote from the [opengroup.org manual on `find`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) hints that `-print0` is non-standard:

> A feature of SVR4's find utility was
>   the -exec primary's + terminator. This
>   allowed filenames containing special
>   characters (especially s) to
>   be grouped together without the
>   problems that occur if such filenames
>   are piped to xargs. Other
>   implementations have added other ways
>   to get around this problem, notably a
>   -print0 primary that wrote filenames with a null byte terminator. **This was
>   considered here, but not adopted.**
>   Using a null terminator meant that any
>   utility that was going to process
>   find's -print0 output had to add a new
>   option to parse the null terminators
>   it would now be reading.

Comment: The -H is not needed with xargs because grep is receiving more than one file on the command line, and in that case it outputs the file name along with the capture; I think it's a standard behavior, and should work also on greps different from yours. Note that it would better to use 'find ... -print0' and pipe the output to 'xargs -0', so that a 0-separator is used, and your command will work also with nasty file names (e.g. containing spaces).

Comment: Note that the other way to deal with the possibility of one file being passed to grep is to add /dev/null to the command, so grep always has at least two files to search.  The '-H' option for grep is not part of the POSIX specification - it is a useful GNU extension.

Comment: I Googled a bit, and I get the idea that -print0 is not POSIX compliant... see near the bottom of this page: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to recursively search, you can just do..

```
grep -H abc *.php
```

..which gives you the desired output. `-H` is the default behaviour (at least on the OS X version of grep), so you can omit this:

```
grep abc *.php
```

You can grep recursively using the `-R` flag, but you're unable limit it to `.php` files:

```
grep -R abc *
```

Again, this has the same desired output.

I know this doesn't exactly answer your questions, it's just.. an alternative... The above are just grep with a single flag, so are easier to remember than `find`/`-exec`/`grep`/`xargs` combinations! (irrelevant for a script, but useful for day-to-day shell'ing)

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path -type f -name "*.php" | awk '
{
    while((getline line<$0)>0){
        if(line ~ /time/){
            print $0":"line
            #do some other things here
        }
    }    
}'
```