# How can I traverse a directory tree using a bash or Perl script?

Tags: perl, bash, unix, directory, traversal

I am interested into getting into bash scripting and would like to know how you can traverse a unix directory and log the path to the file you are currently looking at if it matches a regex criteria.

It would go like this:

- Traverse a large unix directory path file/folder structure.
- If the current file's **contents** contained a string that matched one or more regex expressions,
- Then append the file's full path to a results text file.

Bash or Perl scripts are fine, although I would prefer how you would do this using a bash script with **grep**, **awk**, etc commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use find and grep

```
find . -exec grep -l -e 'myregex' {} \; >> outfile.txt
```

`-l` on the grep gets just the file name

`-e` on the grep specifies a regex

`{}` places each file found by the find command on the end of the grep command

`>> outfile.txt` appends to the text file

Comment: -exec grep will be rather slow, as it runs grep for every file separately

Comment: You can speed it up considerably with a plus sign: find . -exec grep -l -e 'myregex' {} + >> outfile.txt

Answer (score 8):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -l -E 'some_regexp' > /tmp/list.of.files
```

Important parts:

- -type f makes the find list only files
- -print0 prints the files separated not by \n but by \0 - it is here to make sure it will work in case you have files with spaces in their names
- xargs -0 - splits input on \0, and passes each element as argument to the command you provided (grep in this example)

The cool thing with using xargs is, that if your directory contains really a lot of files, you can speed up the process by paralleling it:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -P 5 -L 100 grep -l -E 'some_regexp' > /tmp/list.of.files
```

This will run the grep command in 5 separate copies, each scanning another set of up to 100 files

Comment: I like this.  I love the fact that you can make commands as simple or complicated as you want depending on the amount of power you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

`grep -l -R <regex> <location>` should do the job.

Comment: -R has given me problems before on certain versions of Unix.  If it works for @Brock Woolf then great, otherwise, he will need to use find and grep together

Comment: It's a GNU grep option.  If his unix version doesn't have it, it's not too hard to install (politics aside).

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to do this from within Perl, you can take the `find` commands that people suggested and turn them into a Perl script with `find2perl`:

If you have:

```
$ find ...
```

make that

```
$ find2perl ...
```

That outputs a Perl program that does the same thing. From there, if you need to do something that easy in Perl but hard in shell, you just extend the Perl program.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path -type f -name "*.txt" | awk '
{
    while((getline line<$0)>0){
        if(line ~ /pattern/){
            print $0":"line
            #do some other things here
        }
    }    
}'
```

similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084266/write-a-shell-script-that-find-greps-and-outputs-filename-and-content-in-1-line/1085221#1085221)

Answer (score 0):

```
find /path -type f -name "outfile.txt" | awk '
{
    while((getline line<$0)>0){
        if(line ~ /pattern/){
            print $0":"line
        }
    }    
}'
```